# Mysql update field

Tags: mysql

I want to update a table's field where said field is equal to something.

For example, I want to do:

```
UPDATE users SET name = 'John' WHERE name = 'Jane'
```

Is this valid syntax or will I get an error?

Comment: Did you try it? Yes it is valid, and yes it will work as you have it.

Comment: Although single-quoted strings are preferable to double-quoted for compatibility with other RDBMS.  `'John'`

Comment: you should learn basic things from http://www.w3schools.com here is link for sql update http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: @HelpMeToAskQuestions FYI, using w3schools as a reference is almost as bad as referencing Wikipedia. http://w3fools.com/

Comment: why so please tell me i believe its good for basic learning

Comment: Because much of their content is out-dated, inconsistent, and sometimes just plain inaccurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that should work just fine.  I would have thought that the use of double-quotes (instead of single quotes) would have thrown an error, but I just tried it and it worked.

Even though double-quotes will work, the use of the single-quotes is the accepted standard.  It's a good idea to get used to using that, just in case you find yourself using an RDBMS (Oracle or MSSQL) that more-tightly enforces ANSI SQL.

Comment: MySQL supports this, even though it's a deviation from the standard SQL:1999.

Comment: I only use single quotes, since I use php to generate the queries. Something like $query = "UPDATE users SET name = '$new_name' WHERE..". I just asked because I didn't know if it was valid to update a field using the same field in the where clause.